# Change Listview in a fragment to horizontal

Tags: android, android-layout

[image: App Image]

I want that bottom listview to be horizontal. That list view is in a fragment.

[image: Code image with error]

Comment: Why don't you paste the code itself instead of an image? If someone would like to modify your code to give a proper example it is easier to copy-paste the required part than to write it from the scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better approach is to use `RecyclerView` and set it horizontal as followed

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager= new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

You can also make your custom listview horizontally, check details in this simple link http://dev-smart.com/horizontal-listview/.
But better to use Recyclerview or HorizontalScroll view.

Comment: Sir I have tried this line of code but the the term "linearLayoutManager" is in color red means it is an error :/

Comment: make sure you have added `compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'` in your build.gradle (module:app) and just import `LinearLayoutManager`.

Comment: see this [example](http://www.android-examples.com/android-simple-recyclerview-example-tutorial) as well

Comment: Sir I imported LinearLayoutManger but the error is still there .. it wont even let me import this.

Comment: have you checked the example? what is the issue exactly?

Comment: I have checked example it is imported now but there is error on {(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);}

Comment: if you are writing it in Fragment, change `this` with `getActivity()`

Comment: Ok that problem is fixed but my list is in custom adapter so do I need to change recyclerview ??

Answer (score 1):

1) First If you need horizontal scrolling you should use RecyclerView in that fragment, even better if you write your own HorizontalListView by extending ViewGroup(its challenging, but i have done that).

2) Read this blog post, i think you need this

http://blog.nkdroidsolutions.com/android-horizontal-vertical-recyclerview-example/

Answer (score 1):

You can go for horizontal listview. Horizontal listview is not provided by android sdk by default. You will have to use a library eg. androidHorizontalListView. 
Use the below line in your app level build.gradle file to use it as a dependency.

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':androidHorizontalListView')
}
```

Then in your xml use

```
 <com.meetme.android.horizontallistview.HorizontalListView
                    android:id="@+id/horList"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    />
```

All the implementations will be same as normal listview. However, it will scroll horizontally.

Please ref : https://github.com/MeetMe/Android-HorizontalListView for details